# "Свежеструганые доски" or "свежеструганные доски"?

Tags: орфография

> Театральные подмостки
>
> Для таких, как мы, бродяг,
>
> Свежеструга(н, нн)ые доски,
>
> Занавески на гвоздях.

This portion of 1991 Russian song («Бродячие артисты») made me think of Н-НН orthography of Russian adjectives and participles again. Such complicate rules! The question is, must we write свежеструганые or свежеструганные? Also, is this an adjective or a passive participle? If possible, can you please provide the specific rule which would explain why have you chosen a single or a double Н for the suffix.

Comment: 1991??? It's 1980-ies or even earlier.

Comment: [1985](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IM46Yd92J4o)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You asked for rules, so here come rules. Specifically, I am referencing the "Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник" (my translation: "Rules of Russian orthography and punctuation. Full academic manual": Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под ред. В.В. Лопатина. — М: Эксмо, 2009. - 480 с.) in its 2009 edition.

But first...

0. What is the base form of the word?

It is `свежеструган(н)ый`.

1. Is this an irregular word?

**No**. Unfortunately, there is no easy way out.

2. This is a compound word where `свеж-` is an additional root stacked on top of another word. Here is where the rules come in:

> §99. В словах с приставкой не-, в сложных словах и в некоторых сочетаниях-повторах формы причастий и прилагательных пишутся так же, как в отдельном (без приставки и не в составе сложного слова или сочетания-повтора) употреблении, т.е. по правилам §98.

With the important part being loosely translated to

> §99. In compound words, forms of participles and adjectives are written in the same way, as in a simple usage, i.e., as stated in §98.

So we can move on to analyzing the word `струган(н)ый` instead.

3. So what does §98 state?

Well, the word does not end with `−ованный`/`−ёванный`/`−еванный`, it is not formed from a perfective (**NOT TO BE CONFUSED WITH PERFECT**) verb, so it leaves us with §98.3:

> Причастия не на −ованный (−ёванный, −еванный) глаголов несовершенного вида (они  образуются только от бесприставочных глаголов) и соотносительные с ними прилагательные пишутся по-разному: причастия с нн, прилагательные — с одним н.

Or

> Participles not ending with −ованный (−ёванный,  −еванный) of imperfective verbs (they are formed only from prefixless verbs) and correlative adjectives are written differently: participles with нн, adjectives with a singular н.

So the choice is down to what part of speech it is. And this is the tricky part: in this case, the same form can be an adjective **or** a participle, depending on the context.

Thankfully, since you have a full sentence, we do have that context. Specifically, §98.3 has a note:

> Примечание. Как видно из примеров, причастие опознается по наличию зависимых слов. Бывают, однако, редкие случаи, когда зависимое слово не является признаком причастия.

Or

> Note: as you can see from examples (yeah, I didn't mention a whole paragraph of examples in 98.3), the participle is identified by the presence of dependencies. There are, however, some rare cases when the dependent word is not a sign of the participle.

Well, thankfully, in your example, the word has no dependent words, so it is an adjective, so we can finally tell that it has a singular `-н-`: `свежеструганый`, or rather `свежеструганые`.

I bet you thought this would be the end of it? **Nope!**

So I checked a couple of sources, and what do you know, things are even more complicated.

First of all, you'll notice that most search engines will be really adamant that you have made a typo. In fact, all of my spell-checkers are going crazy: "this word must be written with two н's!"

[Wiktionary](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) will yell at you:

> Такое написание слова ошибочно! Вы, возможно, имели в виду свежеструганный?

But then I found it: Russian Orthographic Dictionary under editorial supervision of V.Lopatin (В. В. Лопатин Русский орфографический словарь: около 180 000 слов. О.Е. Иванова, В.В. Лопатин (отв. ред.), И.В. Нечаева, Л.К. Чельцова. / Российская академия наук; Институт русского языка им. В.В. Виноградова. — Москва, 2004. 2-е изд., испр. и доп. — М.: 2007.) has an entry:

> свежеструганый
> свежестр'уганый и свежестр'оганый

(there is an alternative form spelled with an `о`)

This dictionary is published under Vinogradov's Institute of Russian Language, a subsidiary of the Russian Academy of Sciences, so it is as official as we are going to get. Even the rules that I am using come from a book by the same people. It even references this dictionary in the preface:

> Наиболее полным нормативным словарем является в настоящее время академический «Русский орфографический словарь».

> The fullest standard dictionary nowadays is the academic "Russian orthographic dictionary".

Also, just to be sure, I also checked Google's Ngram viewer:
[image: Usage of свежеструганый and свежеструганный plotted by Google Books Ngram Viewer]

Alternatively:

[image: Usage of свежеструганые and свежеструганные plotted by Google Books Ngram Viewer]

So both forms are clearly present in similar quantities in real texts. But recently, there has been a sharp drop off for seemingly no good reason (other than a mistake being propagated through the interwebs).

So there you have it: the word is spelled with a single `-н-` and if you use it like this, no one will ever believe you are right :D

Comment: lately (last 10-15 years) issues official  dictionaries and school  textbooks give impression that authors weren't well-versed themselves...  I heard of two н version from there

Answer (score 5):

Конечно, свежеструганые. Отглагольное прилагательное, без зависимых слов и прочих фишек.

Две -н- было бы с приставкой, сравните: свежеструганые — свежевыструганные (приставка вы-).

Answer (score 3):

It's an adjective because something can be свежеструган(н)ым and it's not a participle because there is no such verb свежестругать.

Let's look at the rules for adjectives:

> В сложных прилагательных типа малохоженый, новоявленный количество Н определяется правописанием отглагольного прилагательного, например:
>
> - свежемороженый от мороженый ← морозить (НСВ) – одна Н,
> - свежезамороженный от замороженный ← заморозить (СВ) – две Н.

> Одна Н пишется в прилагательных, образованных от бесприставочных глаголов несовершенного вида без зависимых слов, потому что при наличии зависимых слов это уже не прилагательные, а причастия, которые в полной форме следует писать только с двумя Н.

[source](https://dict.nsu.ru/mod/book/view.php?id=11&chapterid=28)

The verb стругать fits these criteria (imperfective, no dependent words).

So it must be **свежеструганый** (one Н).

Comment: @Heagon, I would argue that свежеструганый cannot take dependencies. It would be incorrect to say, e.g. *свежеструганные плотником Васей доски. Can you think of any dependencies that would sound ok?